# RoR Asset Pipeline Generating Extra Links

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I seem to be having some odd behavior with the Rails Asset Pipeline.  I have broken down my CSS by sub-domain (admin, forum, user, etc.), and have created individual manifest files.  The CSS files are also placed in the appropriate sub-directory within the app/assets/stylesheets directory.  The issue I am experiencing is I'll specify the appropriate manifest file to use in the stylesheet_link_tag, but when I view the HTML source, the compiled css, and all of the individual css files are linked.  Below is an example:

Ruby Version 1.9.3

Rails Version 3.2.14

Configuration in `application.rb`

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.assets.precompile += ['forum.css', 'application.css']
```

Manifest File `/app/assets/stylesheets/forum.css`

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require_self
*= require_tree ./forum_styles/
*/
```

There is a `table.css.scss` file in the /app/assets/stylesheets/forum_styles directory

The `application.html.haml` layout

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Forum"
    = stylesheet_link_tag "forum"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    #breadcrumbs= yield :breadcrumbs
    #main_wrapper
      #flash-message-container
        = render "shared/flash_message"
      = yield
```

When I precompile the assets, restart the application server, go to the Index page and view the HTML source, I see the following:

```
<head>
  <title>Forum</title>
  <link href="/assets/forum.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/forum_styles/table.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="rCm2oS+Role4CXdIKoLSkNLYVMdpDVxCb2GS+ajk7EQ=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

Even tough I only specified the forum.css file in the stylesheet_link_tag, two .css files are linked; effectively doubling the css loaded by the browser.  I have verified the CSS in both files is identical.  Is this normal behavior, or is there something I need to change in my configuration to only link the compiled forum.css?  Also, I noticed there is no MD5 hash on the css links; just `?body=1`.  But I haven't been too worried about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in development mode, that mechanism is offered to help you debug things. If you switch to production mode you will have a single link to one CSS file with everything merged in, minimized (but you need to precompile assets to run in production, remember to destroy precompiled assets if you switch back to development).

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the explanation.  I've been beating my head against the wall for no reason.

Comment: Ok, followup question.  Is there a way to disable that behavior in Development as it is causing javascript code to fire multiple times?

Comment: Yes it's possible, config.assets.debug = false as stated here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off